Extracting more than 25 rows from REST API using tRest and tExtractJSONFields
I'm currently working on extracting data from a REST API using Talend's tRest and tExtractJSONFields components. However, I'm facing an issue where I'm only able to extract a maximum of 25 rows, despite the fact that the dataset contains many more entries.
Here's the workflow I'm using, and I've noticed that regardless of the queries I try, I'm consistently limited to 25 rows. I suspect there might be a pagination or limit setting that I'm missing.
Could anyone guide me on how to navigate the JSON to effectively extract more than 25 rows, and bypass the pagination ? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated!
Here is the workflow and my count : 

Hi from what I can see the JSON only contains 25 elements (there is no limit in the tExtractJSONFields), but the total dataset has 2881, there must be parameters in the API (most like offset or limit) to access the rest of the data, you need to loop on the rest api like (https://www.test.com/data?offset=0, https://www.test.com/data?offset=25, https://www.test.com/data?offset=50, ...)

Yes, that's the conclusion we've come to.  Is there a way to iterate the tRest to include the paginated results ?

So first you need to extract the number of objects there is the Rest API and use it to get the number of iteration for the tRest.
So the job would look like this :

In the first tExtractJSONFields you retreive the count value like this :

In the tJavaRow you divide that value by 25 and round it up like this :

And store that value in a globalVar, I used the tFlowToIterate to do that.
The you use a tLoop with the configuration like this :

To navigate your paginated data in the API and I store it in a tHashOutput.
Hope this helps

Hi @emiledadou Thank you for your answer. I can't seem to make ".iter" work, is there a workaround ? Also, I do not have a tHashOutput (I work with TOS), is there a library I need to download or call ?

Hi for the tHashOutput, it's not shown by default so to have it in the Palette you need to go to the Project Parameters (File > Project Parameters) and then go to Designer > Palette Parameters, select tHashInput and tHashOutput and click on the arrow on the right to import it in the Palette. As for the "iter" did you create it in the output of the tJavaRow ?

Thanks for the tips about the palette, I added the two tools. As for iter, I copied what you wrote : iter.row8 = Math.round(row7.count / 25); I did try a globalMap, but I get an error, something about a conversion, and JVM compatibility

it's in a tJavaRow it always use input_row and output_row regardless of the name of the input and output, you have to write directly output_row.iter = Math.round(input_row.count / 25);

When I wrote input and output_row, I got the same error : "iter cannot be resolved or is not a field". Should I instanciate .iter ?

Alright, I figured out what was wrong. iter was not in the output schema of the tjavarow. and so, was not in the schema of the tlogrow that followed. Thank you for your help.
